# How do I get a list of installed webcams?

Tags: delphi, driver, webcam

How can I get all available webcam drivers on a computer?
I want to display the drivers in a combo box.

Comment: And the answer is probably "with a WMI query."  We've got an expert on WMI and Delphi who's fairly active; if he shows up he can probably give you a good answer.

Comment: Do you want `installed webcams` ( which are **devices**) or `available webcam drivers` (which are **drivers**)? They're not the same thing, and how to get each of them is drastically different.

Answer (score 10):

To enumerate the webcams, you can use the the [System Device Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the [`CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GUID which will get all the  Video capture devices.

Try this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  ActiveX,
  DirectShow9,
  ComObj;

procedure EnumerateVideoInputDevices;
const
  IID_IPropertyBag          : TGUID = '{55272A00-42CB-11CE-8135-00AA004BB851}';
var
  LDevEnum : ICreateDevEnum;
  ppEnumMoniker    : IEnumMoniker;
  pceltFetched : ULONG;
  Moniker    : IMoniker;
  PropBag    : IPropertyBag;
  pvar       : olevariant;
  hr         : HRESULT;
  i          : integer;
begin
  CocreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICreateDevEnum, LDevEnum);
  hr := LDevEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, ppEnumMoniker, 0);
  if (hr = S_OK) then
  begin
    while(ppEnumMoniker.Next(1, Moniker, @pceltFetched) = S_OK) do
      begin
        Moniker.BindToStorage(nil, nil, IID_IPropertyBag, PropBag);
        if PropBag.Read('Description', pvar, nil) = S_OK then
          Writeln(Format('Description    %s',[String(pvar)]));
        if PropBag.Read('FriendlyName', pvar, nil) = S_OK then
          Writeln(Format('Friendly Name  %s',[String(pvar)]));
        if PropBag.Read('DevicePath', pvar, nil) = S_OK then
          Writeln(Format('Device  Path    %s',[String(pvar)]));
        if PropBag.Read('CLSID', pvar, nil) = S_OK then
          Writeln(Format('CLSID           %s',[String(pvar)]));
        PropBag := nil;
        Moniker := nil;
      end;
  end;
  ppEnumMoniker :=nil;
  LDevEnum :=nil;
end;



begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      EnumerateVideoInputDevices;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```